# Getting the value of a variable in a twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to fill an array in a twig template after comparing two first ones. This is my example.

```
{% set tab = {} %}
{% for key, value in array  %}
   {% for k, v in array2  %}
          {% if value.name == v %}
              {% set tab = tab | merge({ k : v}) %}
          {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this part of code `{% set tab = tab | merge({ k : v}) %}` I'm trying to get the value of the key for the second array to fill the new one with the right key and value. The problem is with i set `k` like a key for the new array.  I am geting a string and not the key value. I want to know how to get the value and not a string variable.

Thanks.

Comment: Twig wasn't designed to shift large amounts of data around! While this might work, if possible I would suggest doing this calculation in the controller or a repository

Comment: It's clear ! Thanks dude

Comment: If related to the view it can be done in a twig extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for the `attribute` function: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html

But as mentioned in the comments, it probably better to encapsulate this logic into the Repository or a service that takes the results of the repository query as parameters and returns a clean array, which is easy to "display" without further complicated processing.

This way the result could be also reused on a CLI command for example cause the data isn't bound to the twig view anymore.